# Problem with playing large (long) audio files in Safari via HTML tag

Tags: safari, html5-audio

I cannot make Safari play large audio files using `audio` tag (in Chrome it works as desired). Is there any limitation in Safari? How to solve the problem of playing too long audio?

This is how I use the tag:

```html
<audio src="test.mp3" contros></audio>
```

[image: Screenshot from Safari of the problem]

Comment: You ever figure this out?